# jQuery animating all elements instead of the next one only

Tags: jquery, css

I was trying to apply animation to the `.typeform` element when I click the `.nexto` element. When using `toggleClass` all the `.typeform` were affected by the `toggleClass`.

I need to apply the animation to the next `.typeform` element when I click the `.nexto`. Please help me on this. Thanks.

```js
$('.nexto').on('click', function(event) {
  $('.typeform-element').toggleClass('animations');
})
```

```css
.animations {
  animation: animation-1 1s linear;
}

@keyframes animation-1 {
  0% {
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: -25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typeform">
  <div class="typeform-element" id="fname">
    <p><span class="list">1</span>&#8594;What's your First Name? *</p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Type your answer..." autofocus>
    <div class="ok-btn">
      <a href="#lname" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="typeform-element" id="lname">
    <p><span class="list">2</span>&#8594;What's Your Last Name? *</p>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Type your answer...">
    <div class="ok-btn">
      <a href="#email" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="typeform-element" id="email">
    <p><span class="list">3</span>&#8594;Let's know your Email Address*</p>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your answer...">
    <div class="ok-btn">
      <a href="#submit" class="nexto">OK &#10004;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="typeform-element" id="submit">
    <div class="ok-btn">
      <a href="#fname">Submit &#10004;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The title is the opposite you want, your code is changing all the element, your aim is to change only the block element next to the clicking one. I suggest to rename the title. And: the first solution of @Mahatmasamatman is pretty good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access your buttons parent, and then select the immediately following sibling, and toggle his class only.

```
$('.nexto').on('click', function(event){
           $(this).closest('.typeform-element').next('.typeform-element').toggleClass('animations');
    });
```